# Typescript pulling keys out of an object that is unknown?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with an `unknown` type, which is basically a map of things. In my case, I have a `String` *key* with a `String` *value*.

```
  export interface CoolInterface {
    field1: number
    field2: string
    field3?: unknown
  }
```

the problem:

```
    const result: CoolInterface = getData(input)
    result.field3[0].map['uri'].includes('some-string'),
```

everything after `result.field3[0].map` causes issues, I assume because the type of map is `unknown`. Assuming I can't modify the interface, how can I do what I'm trying to achieve above?

Comment: What does field 3 look like? And are you trying to map the first array of `field3` or is `map` a property of the first object in field3 that has a property `uri`?

Comment: Field 3 is {string: string} in my current case

Comment: ok, if the type is `{string: string}`, doing `[0].map['uri']` on it won't work.

Comment: That is why I'm asking the question...

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the property with type `unknown` to the type you expect it to be, that way you let the compiler know it's ok.

```
const result: CoolInterface = { 
  field1: 3, 
  field2: "string", 
  field3: ["someuri", "some-string"] 
};

const unkownField = result.field3 as string[]; // cast as x type (for example string array)
console.log(unkownField.map(s => s.includes('some-string'))); // no error
```